# Session Automatically Expires After 55 to 60 Seconds In ASP.NET MVC With WEB API

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have issue that is Session Automatically Expires even session time-out sets to it maximum level. I am developing my web application in a ASP.NET MVC 5 With WEB API .
There is no issue when I run it in local but when I publish it on web it session automatically expires within 55-60 seconds. Hosting provider also says that there is no issue with their server. I can not find any error and don't know how to configure it .
My < system.web > configuration in web.config file is as follow .
Check this link - http://pastebin.com/uvPVKDQU

Please help me . Thanks In Advance !!!!!!!

Comment: did you really try to set your session timeout to 100000 minutes?

Comment: I have made it to 30 but no result .. issue remains same ... @Claies

Answer (score -1):

The session timeout value is set on the session tag.

```
 <sessionstate mode="inproc" timeout=30 />
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: but timeout can be defined by your desired timeout . there is no issue with thattt ...

Comment: I have made it to 30 but no result .. issue remains same ... @Claies

Comment: When you say that the session expires, what do you mean? What specifically happens?

Comment: When user logged into the system after successfully login user can be able to access the system but after 55-60 seconds user automatically redirected to again login page. Which means session expires and redirected to login page ... got it Tim ??

Comment: That's not session that's the login which can or cannot be tied together. What steps have you taken to troubleshoot? What is your authentication setup as? Forms? Basic?

Comment: This is the issue is arise only due to " SESSION EXPIRATION ". In login form I have checked that user is authorized or not if yes them user can be able to access the system. User successfully redirected to HomePage after login USER can access the whole system and user can but it only for hardly 55-60 seconds after that user automatically redirected to LOGIN PAGE again which is happened due to SESSION EXPIRATION . You can see my <system.web> section in following url :- http://pastebin.com/uvPVKDQU